# scrollToFixed - weird scrolling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I am trying to do a simple fixed-while-scrolling with [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed), but I have encountered some weird behavior

I have prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guyisra/kspA8/2/) that shows the following problems:

html:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="car_left_col" class="span2">left</div>
    <div id="car_center" class="span8">
        <div class="car_main thumbnail">
            <div class="car_cover">
                <img alt="" src="http://www.autopulze.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Rolls-Royce-Silver-Ghost-the-Best-Car-in-the-World.jpg">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="car_page_creator"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="car_talk">here are the comments for the car</div>
    </div>
    <div id="car_right_col" class="span2">
        <div class="car_vote test_fixed">I should not move</div>
    </div>
    <div class="long"></div>
```

css:

```
.long {
    height: 10000px;
}
#car_right_col {
    position: relative;
}
.car_main {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
.car_cover {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.car_cover img {
    width: 100%;
}
.test_fixed {
    position: static;
}
.car_vote {
    position: relative;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test_fixed').scrollToFixed({
        marginTop: 45,
        limit: $('.car_page_creator').offset().top
    });

});
```

1. when scrolling all the way down, notice a horizontal scroll bar, stretching the page ridiculously to the right
2. I assume this has to do with the first issue, the item to be fixed, `.test-fixed`, has a really big `left` property when scrolled down
3. when scrolling up (from all the way down) by click and holding the scrollbar, once it reaches the point of fixing the item, it just erratically

I think that my html and css is pretty much standard with nothing special.. Is this behavior due to my code or bugs in the plugin?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: try with this full screen http://jsfiddle.net/guyisra/kspA8/2/embedded/result/  - note that there are 2 scrollbars, so the horizontal is visible at the most bottom

Comment: I see, that is quite strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue in [github](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed/issues/87), and a I must say that response was quick

the solution was to remove the element `.test-fixed` outside of the right column and make it the same level as the center div

Comment: Perfect! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

I've updated your fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/kspA8/17/embedded/result/

```
.test_fixed {
  position: static;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

Applying auto left property to your context element seems to have fixed it : )

Comment: this does work in the jsfiddle, but unforunatly for me, it doesn't work in the real website. I've added the solution found working

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on stackoverflow so I'm not sure if I'm doing this quite right =).

I disabled the javascript you used to make the 'I should not move'-div stick to the right and 45px from the top. You can easily do this with css only. Use position **fixed** and give the div a margin top.

The second problem was you were trying to fix the div's child. The parent was still positioned relative.

Replace the original #car_right_col with this piece of code. Hope it works for ya!

```
#car_right_col {
   margin-top:45px;
   position: fixed;
   right:0px;
}
```

Edit: If I just paste the modified fiddle url will it work? =) http://jsfiddle.net/kspA8/16/

Edit2: I just checked out the ScrollToFixed plugin demo. Seems you might need a different answer after all.. Sorry!

Comment: No...it should only remain fixed until you reach the target element.

Comment: I figured later on. Guess I didn't fully understood your question. The answer provided by blend seems to work! =)